# How to access module variable from module dir to theme directory?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I want to access a variable in theme directory which I have declared in a custom module.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, you must register HOOK on install function in your module. Second, you must assign variables in your registered HOOK. For example:

```
function hookDisplayPDFInvoice($params)
{

}
```

And here you can as Darshan soni said you can assign variables using smarty assign:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'var' => $var,
            'var' => $var,
            'var' => $var
        ));
```

And return data to your .tpl file. But if you register module hook for example: HOOK EXTRA LEFT , this hook exist in product.tpl file, so you can access data in product.tpl file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your module variable to theme file using $smarty->assign() function in your custom module file.